# How to a count a specific digit in a number with javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, do-while

I am trying to write a block of code which will separate digits (with modulus operator) in a number first and count how many digit "6" are there in the number.

I tried so many things but I think I have logic problem with the way I think.

```
output = [];

var count = 0;


while (a > 0){
  output.push(a % 10);
  a = Math.floor(a/10);
  if(a == 6){
      count++;
    }
}
```

When I run this code on Safari, It shows the entered number as it is, but it shows "0" for the variable count.

Comment: Convert to a string and find the `"6"`es?

Comment: Since this is a homework, I am not allowed to convert the number to a string.

Comment: var chars = a+"".split(''); should return a array of chars which you can now count by a simple for next loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.floor(a/10)` doesn't give the current digit. `a % 10` gives the current digit.

You have check if the current digit `a % 10` is `6`.

**Live Example:**

```js
let output = [];
let count = 0;
let a = 1667;

while (a > 0) {
  let digit = a % 10;
  output.push(digit);
 
  if (digit == 6) {
    count++;
  }
    
  a = Math.floor(a / 10);
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You know the last digit, so you can subtract it and divide with 10, instead of using `Math.floor`.

```
let number = 1626364656; // has 5 sixes
let sixesCount = 0;
while (number > 0) {
    const digit = number % 10;
    if (digit === 6) {
        sixesCount++;
    }
    number = (number - digit) / 10;
}
console.log('Found', sixesCount, 'sixes.'); // "Found 5 sixes."
```